# Java: RoundingMode Error- cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I have the following line of code in my Java `println` statement:

```
 System.out.println("Iteration: " + counter + "\tRoot: " +
           new BigDecimal(x_iter).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
```

But I kept getting this error and I am not sure why:

```
nth_root.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                           new BigDecimal(x_iter).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable RoundingMode
  location: class nth_root
nth_root.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                           new BigDecimal(x_iter).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
                               ^
  symbol:   class BigDecimal
  location: class nth_root
2 errors
```

Is there a library that I need to import before using `BigDecimal` ? What am I missing ? Note that my Java version is :

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: import java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: You should be using an IDE that deals with imports automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is saying "cannot find symbol" because it doesn't know what `RoundingMode` and `BigDecimal` are. You need to tell it by importing both `RoundingMode` and `BigDecimal` from the `java.math` library:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

Or you import all the classes in `java.math`:

```
import java.math.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to import a library and that is :

```
java.math.*;
```